# jQuery ignore leading and trailing whitespace while sending request to remote URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am currently trying to make a simple jQuery autocomplete UI where the search term is sent back to a PHP backend, which in turn queries a MySQL database for matching term and sends back results. This works fine..except that, if I input 3-4 whitespaces, it sends a request as well, and this returns all results from backend. How do I configure jQuery autocomplete such that whatever term has been typed in, the search term that should go to the backend should have its leading and trailing whitespaces trimmed, and after trimming, if it is found to be a blank string, send no request at all?

I found multiple examples in SO, but all of them involve a built-in array of terms as example, I can't figure out how to configure the `source` parameter if its value is  remote URL:

```
$("#myinput").autocomplete({
        source: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/autoComplete/",
        appendTo: "#search-holder",
        response: function(e,y) {}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy answer for this one. I thought the `search` event allows an term overwrite but alas it doesn't. Nagaraju's answer is correct, only he didn't show actual implementation. Here's how it should look like

```
$( "#myinput" ).autocomplete({
    source : function(request, response){
      //trim the input value
      request.term = request.term.trim();
      if(request.term == ""){
          //when empty, returns empty result
          response([]);
      }else{
          //our own implementation of request to the server
          $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/autoComplete/?term=" + request.term, 
            function(data) {
                response(data);
            });
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the `response` function here?

Comment: it's a callback that notifies the autocomplete that the request is done

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Update your `source` function as the following:

```
    source: function( request, response ) {
       //Remove spaces 
      var matcher = new RegExp($.trim(request.term).replace(/ +/g, ""), "i" );
      response($.grep(resources, function(value) {
         return matcher.test( value);
      }));   
    }
```

Comment: Where did you mention the remote URL?

Comment: @SexyBeast in response code resoruces would contain the remote resource as I see it

Comment: Umm no, I don't understand it still. Can you give a complete example, showing where to provide the URL?

Answer (score -1):

Use `trim()` to remove white-space from end and beginning of a string?
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Or you could do it at the backend.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Edit:
Why not just get all available autocompletion's once with an AJAX call when you load the page and store them in an array. This way the DB would only be bothered once when the page is loaded instead of every time there's a change in the input field. Also this would take some workload of the DB and the white space wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I know how to trim text, problem is, how to tell jQuery that if the trimmed text has zero length, not send a request at all?

Comment: Yes, I can do at the backend, that means the request has already been made. I don't even want to send a request if the search term is only whitespace.

Comment: There will be over 10 million results. Caching them in the frontend will be awful for user's memory.